# Pandas Dataframe: how do I drop columns with NaNs in column pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Beginner in Pandas here and for a project I am getting dataframes likes this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "x", np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "y", np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "z", np.nan]]

cols = [("column1", "first"), ("column1", "last"), ("column2", "first"), ("column2", "last"), ("column3", "first"), ("column3", "last")]

df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=cols)
```

I am getting pairs of columns and want to drop all columns where all elements of both parts of the pair are NaN. For the given code I'd expect the last column pair. Expected result:

| column3 / first | column3 / last |
| --- | --- |
| x | nan |
| y | nan |
| z | nan |

I have tried pandas.dropna() with different subsets but I cant get it to work that the last column is not deleted. The name of the columns are variable but always 2 levels deep.

Can some Pandas-God help this poor soul?

Comment: Hello, so our ouput would be to see only (column3, first) column ?

Comment: No I would achieve that by using pd.dropna(how="all"). I would expect the last two columns ie:
column3 first column3 second
x                           nan
y                           nan
z                           nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols))

#if nott create it
#df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=cols)
#df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

For each first level values test if all values are missing by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and then test if at least one `True` per columns by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), chain inverted mask by `~` and `|` for bitwise `OR` and filter in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = ~df.isna().groupby(level=0, axis=1).transform('all').any()
m2 = ~df.isna().any()

df = df.loc[:, m1 | m2]
print(df)
  column3     
    first last
0       x  NaN
1       y  NaN
2       z  NaN
```